# Space counter not functioning in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a word counter in java. I'm trying to count words by separating them with spaces.

I've managed to get rid of the spaces before or after a sentence with the trim function. However, I haven't been able to adjust for the case that the user types more than one space in between two words. For example, so far the string "hello world" with multiple spaces between hello and world, would output a word count greater than two. This is the code that I have tried so far to fix this problem.

```
public void countWord(){

    String tokens[] = userInput.trim().split(" ");
    int counter = tokens.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
        if(Objects.equals(" ", tokens[i])) {
            --counter;
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("Total word count is: %d", counter);
}
```

As you can see I create a word counting integer that holds the number of tokens created. Then I try and look for a token that only contains " " then decrement the word count by the amount of those strings. However this is not solving my problem.

Comment: Split already removes all spaces, so the for loop is redundant.

Comment: When you do a split by spaces you get a words separated by spaces without them. If you want to count words then just call tokens.lebgth

Comment: Maybe its not a standard space character. Try splitting on all whitespace `split("\\s+")`

Answer (score 3):

You've already `split()` on spaces, so there will be no more spaces in any of the tokens as [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) returns:

> the array of strings computed by splitting this string *around* matches of the given regular expression

(Emphasis mine)
However if there are extra spaces in your `String` there will be extra tokens, which will throw off the length. Instead use `split("\\s+")`. Then just return the length of the `Array`, as `split()` already will return all the tokens separated by spaces, which will be all the words:

```
System.out.printf("Total word count is: %d", tokens.length);
```

Which will print `5` for the test `String`

```
"Hello this   is a String"
```

Comment: `split()` will return 3 tokens if there are two spaces between 2 words. For example, "hello  world" will give 3 tokens, so this will not work.

Comment: The first part of your answer will not work, so I suggest your remove it. :)

Comment: @KushagraGoyal I edited my answer to explain that if there are more spaces it will throw things off

Comment: That worked but I'm just wondering what is the meaning behind \\s+

Comment: It is the regular expression of `\\s` which is a whitespace, and then `+` which means one or more times @User9123

Comment: @User9123 Here are the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 3):

Try regex to split

```
userInput.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are intended to count the words, give a try to one of the followings:
Among those that others mentioned.

1. Here, this solution uses [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

```java
String words = "The Hello World     word counter by using     StringTokenizer";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(words);
System.out.println(st.countTokens()); // => 8
```

2. This way you can take an advantage of regexp by using it to split the string by words

```java
String words = "The Hello World     word counter by using     regex";
int counter = words.split("\\w+").length;
System.out.println(counter); // => 8
```

3. Use [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for your own `counter` method:

```java
public static int counter(String words) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(words);
    int count = 0;
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        count += 1;
        scanner.next();
    }
    return count;
}
```

If you want to count the spaces as you said in the title, you can use [`StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from Commons

```java
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("The Hello World     space counter by using     StringUtils", " ");
System.out.println(count);
```

Or if you use Spring the [`SpringUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html) is also available for you.

```java
int count = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf("The Hello World     space counter by using     Spring-StringUtils", " ");
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily fix it by checking if a `tokens[i].equals("")`. Thus checking if a word is an empty string. Since splitting on a `space` when using multiple spaces creates empty string objects in the array, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get rid of all occurrences of 2 or more adjacent spaces and then split:

```
String tokens[] = userInput.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ").split(" ");
```